# Easiest was to display undefined elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

here's the basic code that I use in cue:

```
<span>{{`${item.name} ${item.surname}`}}</span>
```

it sometimes shows

```
John Doe
```

and sometimes

```
Mary undefined
```

what's the easiest way to not show variable if it's falsy?

I know I can use

```
<span>{{`${item.name} ${item.surname ? item.surname : ''}`}}</span>
```

but it doesn't look clean to me

Comment: use if statement, catch the value if is undefined donot console it

Answer (score 3):

Try it with the or operator `||`

```
<span>{{`${item.name} ${item.surname || ''}`}}</span>
```

Comment: @zbyshekh the value on the right side is your default value if the left value is undefined

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this approach.

```
<span v-if="item.name !== undefined && item.surnam !== undefined">{{`${item.name} ${item.surname}`}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a cleaner way then you can try considering this

```
if(item.surname == undefined){
    item.surname = ''
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use this below function in order to get the name with the correct formatting. Hope this helps.

```js
const getName = (nameObj = {}) => {
  let name = "";

  if (nameObj.name) {
    name = {...nameObj}.name.concat(" ");
  }

  if (nameObj.surname) {
    name = name.concat(nameObj.surname);
  }

  return name.trim();
};

console.log(getName({name: "John", surname: "Doe"}))
console.log(getName({name: "John"}))
console.log(getName({surname: "Doe"}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ternary operator
${(var === undefined)? 'display-none':'display-block'}

Answer (score 0):

if you use vue-cli 4, I suggest using operational chaining and nullish coalescing which is a modern technique in babel. This will be a lot helpful in a super nested object.

```
<span>{{`${item.name} ${item?.surname ?? ""}`}}</span>
```

More info on this :https://blog.logrocket.com/optional-chaining-and-nullish-coalescing-in-javascript/

Otherwise, `||` will do the job

```
<span>{{`${item.name} ${item.surname || ''}`}}</span>
```